# FME Dynamic schema error - Features With No Schema defined

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I'm trying to update a column in an ArcSDE table using the sde30 reader/writers.

Keep getting an error:

> Features With No Schema defined

and no features are updated.

Scrolling up there is a message in the log:

> readschema resulted in 0 features

The reader and writer are pointing at the same db and table.

I have the writer in update mode, with 'standard feature_type' dynamic schema based on the reader (as I don't want to update all columns, just one per run which i alter dynamically)

I had it working well with the geodb writer, but switched to sde30 for performance reasons.

If I set the 'feature types to read' on the reader, I no longer get the schema missing error, instead I get:

> Error retrieving dbtune keyword list:SDE_ERROR_CODE(-66) Invalid
>   parameter value passed to function

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you've got your reader configured wrong.

Start with a fresh reader, and don't write anything yet, but add an inspector. Check that you're getting features in. Once you are definitely getting features in, then set up the rest of your logic.

I assume you'll already know this, but if you want to update only particular attributes, you'll need to set up a writer that isn't dynamic. Set it up with your key attribute, and the attributes you're updating, and set it as an 'UPDATE' writer, and you should be good.

Comment: readded the reader and still getting the sde error code above, recreated the writer too, and set the schema to static, with the same result.  (the frustrating thing is i think i've hit this SDE problem before, can't remember what it was though!) something with usernames perhaps.)

Comment: Think my problem has moved on - the schema error has disappeared for now, replaced by this SDE one - I'll post this as a new question.